# CloudFormation EC2 Windows Administrator Password

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation

I'm creating EC2 Windows instances with help of CloudFormation. If you want to connect to Windows instance you have to go [through this steps](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/WindowsGuide/connecting_to_windows_instance.html).

One of steps requires administrator username and password. You can manually check password at CLI. But *could I write admin's username/password t Outputs section of my CloudFormation stack?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few ways to would be suitable.

- Take in parameters for username and password for CloudFormation.  Use the NoEcho parameter.  You can then do a `!Ref AdminPassword` in the output but this is really not a good idea.

Template

```
Parameters:
  AdminPassword:
    Description: Admin Password
    Type: String
    NoEcho: true
    MinLength: 8
    MaxLength: 32
    ConstraintDescription: Must be at least 8 chars long
```

You also need to add this to userdata using !Sub to string replace

```
<powershell>
cmd.exe /c net user /add admin ${AdminPassword}
cmd.exe /c net localgroup administrators admin /add
cmd.exe /c NET localgroup "Remote Desktop Users" admin /ADD
<powershell>
```

- You can run the **aws cli**

```
aws ec2 --region ap-southeast-2 get-password-data --priv-launch-key secret.pem --instance-id i-123123124
```

- SSM parameters are a good option too

Answer (score 0):

Not sure there is a direct way to get the password in the outputs section of CFN template, but you may call a lambda with the API Call getpassworddata
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/API_GetPasswordData.html

This link explains how you can call the lambda function to retrieve any output via an s3 object
[Can AWS CloudFormation call the AWS API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38983926/can-aws-cloudformation-call-the-aws-api)